# Can 2 await function run one after one?

Tags: mongodb, express

I have my Node/Express server and I'm trying to save a user, and after that to generate a key and send an activation email.

I guess that my coding problem is that i'm using 2 "await" functions one after another.

My user is being created but no key generated.

I'm a totally beginner and dumb :)) so sorry if this is not explained perfectly

```
try {
    const savedUser = await user.save();
    //activation key generation and email send
    const tokenkey = await new Key({
        userId: user._id,
        token: crypto.randomBytes(32).toString("hex"),
      }).save();
      console.log(tokenkey);
      
   const message = `${process.env.BASE_URL}/user/verify/${user.id}/${token.token}`;
    await sendEmail(user.email, "Verify Email", message);
    //all ok, send user obj
    res.send({user: user._id, email: user.email, active: user.active, admin: user.admin});
    
} catch (err) {
    res.status(400).send(err);
}
```

Comment: What is your question exactly? Using await multiple times is perfectly fine.